# Find the set of values of $\lambda$ for which $\lambda+ (1-\lambda) \cos^3 x-\cos^2 x\ge 0$ for $x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

Find the set of values of $\lambda$ for which $\lambda+ (1-\lambda) \cos^3 x-\cos^2 x\ge 0$ for $x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}).$

**NOTE: This is simplified version of a much larger problem**

Had the inequation been quadratic, I could have easily solved. I am not familiar with evaluating such problems for cubic polynomials. For the given domain, $\cos x >0$, so that shouldn’t add any complexity to the solution.

How should it be solved?

Comment: Do you want the inequality to be true **for all** $x \in [0, \pi/2)$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve wrt to $\lambda$
$$\lambda\ge\frac{\cos ^2(x)}{\cos ^2(x)+\cos (x)+1}$$
as maximum value of RHS on the interval $[0,\pi/2)$ is $\frac{1}{3}$, the inequality is verified for any $\lambda \ge \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Did you use derivatives for finding the maxima (just curious!)

Comment: @Aditya yes, but graphing helped... Indeed that is not the absolute maximum. The absolute maximum occurs out of the given interval and is $1$